# Spatial light modulator to generate LG beams

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

I am learning to use spatial light modulator. My problem is multiple rings coming out when I put the 1st mask (generating optical vortex) on SLM. It should be LG(0,-1) with only one ring. I did not know where other rings come from.

Comment: Are you sure that you can get patterns with 100% efficiency? Usually you will lose some powers to higher diffraction orders. If you are using things like digital mirror device, even at the blaze angle, I think the diffraction efficiency is on the order of 10%.

Comment: It may be possible to answer your question if you include a drawing or photo, and some more detailed information about your mask.  Most likely it is a problem with the code you're using to specify the mask.